# How to add Xml File Into Project(after deployment) Using User Interface?

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have one DemoQuestion.Xml,after deploying project i want to upload DemoQuestion.xml file with different Question Using USer Interface(such as Admin add New Question To test)
DemoQuestion.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quiz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="quiz.xsd">
  <mchoice>
    <question>Sum of 20 and 30?</question>
    <answer>20</answer>
    <answer correct="yes">50</answer>
    <answer>10</answer>
    <answer>11</answer>
  </mchoice>
  <mchoice>
   </quiz>
i want to add <answer Correct="yes">This attribute in xml how to do it?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimalistic code snippet...

```
string file = Server.MapPath("~/file.xml");

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(file);

        var answers = doc.SelectNodes("//answer");

        if (answers != null && answers.Count > 0)
        {
            XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("correct");
            attr.Value = "yes";

            answers[0].Attributes.Append(attr);
        }

        doc.Save(file);
```

All it does is load the document from a file, retrieves all answer elements and adds the "correct" attribute  with the value of "yes" to the first answer found.

Hope it helps illustrate the solution

Leo

Comment: It very helpful but after adding attribute from user interface in project window it ask to reload project giving message .xml file updated outside the scope ,how should i automatically update file after inserting attribute after deploying project on server

Comment: I don't understand the question.  All the message is saying is that the file has been modified and it's asking you want to reload it because the one you have open in visual studio is out of date. I suppose you won't have the file open in visual studio in a production server.

Comment: i am just making demo project

Comment: Didn't that answer your question?

Comment: i have xml file in visual studio but when i add new element using user interface it should give the message to save file if i cancle it the add element not display in xml file

Comment: how to autoupadate xml file after adding new element to it?

Comment: What do you mean how to autoupdate it????? I've never heard that term. I told you already,  it's already been updated! !!!! Close the file and don't override it. If you click cancel you are overriding the file AFTER it has been updated.

Comment: Mate, out of respect to the community,  either mark this as an answer or delete this question and read a tutorial about how to use computers before you attempt to write programming code